# Safari crossrider extension bad image

Tags: browser, safari-extension, browser-extension, crossrider

I have a browser extension that works and looks fine in all major browsers except safari. The problem is that the icon of the extension near the address bar doesn't show correct image, instead it shows a black square. I tried both .png and .jpg icon image.

Any advice is apreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When choosing an icon to work for Safari, please bear in mind the following Safari limitation as noted in the Crossrider documentation:

All transparent pixels are rendered in white and *all other pixels are rendered in black*. Hence, icons that do not have any transparent pixels appear as a black square.